# C++ freeing pointer inside pointer to structure passed as thread lpParam

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, malloc, free

I have a point in my VC++ program where I have to create a new thread and pass as lpParam an int and a string. So what i've done so far is this (erasing pointer/error checks):

```
typedef struct _chThParam {
    int c;
    char *s;
} chThParam;

DWORD WINAPI startSession(LPVOID lpParam){
    chThParam *param = (chThParam *)lpParam;
    //do something with param
    free(param->ip);
    free(param);
    return 0;
}

void handleResp(int c, char *s){
    chThParam *param;
    param = (chThParam *)malloc(sizeof(chThParam));
    param->c = c;
    param->s = (char *)malloc(strlen(s));
    strcpy(param->s, s);
    ::chTh = CreateThread(NULL, 0, startSession, param, 0, chThId);
}
```

The conflict is in `free(param->ip);` with the message:

```
Debug Error!
HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#200) at 0x005BB908.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.
```

The `free(param);` has no problem.

I have a rule that is: a call to malloc means a call to free. Here two mallocs, then two frees. But the I get this message.

So the question is why can't I free that string! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should change your rules. In C++ use `new` and `delete` and never `malloc` and `free` except for compatibility with libraries that **require** it. Then your next rule should be to rarely if ever use `new` and `delete`.

Comment: The CRT that ships with Visual Studio places guard bytes around allocated memory (in Debug builds) with a predefined pattern. When calling `free` the CRT checks whether those guard bytes still have their initial values. If they don't you get the diagnostic message you posted. So in your case you wrote beyond the end of the buffer pointed to by `param->ip` (see [answer by typ1232](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19644325/1889329)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
param->s = (char *)malloc(strlen(s));
strcpy(param->s, s);
```

Here you are allocating strlen(s) amounts of bytes, but then writing s+1 bytes with strcpy including the null terminator of c strings. This can corrupt an internal heap structure and make any following malloc and free fail.